# Is setTimeout a valid way to avoid stackoverflow when using callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback, stack-overflow

Say I want to create some callback hell, such as :

```
function handleUserInput(callback) {
    ...
} 

function get(uri, callback) {
    ...
}

function processResponseInWorker(callback) {
    ....
}

function updateIndexedDB(callback) {
    ...
}

function updateUI() {
    ...
} 

handleUserInput(get(hot_uri,processResponseInWorker(updateIndexedDB(updateUI()))));
```

This is mostly academic since the stack only gets 5 high.

In fact, is there even a stack at all? Since these calls will return immediately, and the callback will only be invoked, outside of these contexts, by whatever asynchronous tasks these functions perform.

Okay, just say there IS a call stack here, if each callback was forced to execute inside a `setTimeout(func,0)` then the calling function would return immediately, the whole chain would return immediately and the functions would be executed off the setTimout queue.

Is that correct?

Comment: The stack is only 1 high since none of these functions are recursive

Comment: @Logan Murphy: it's not. Infinite recursion is not the only cause for the stack overflow. You can generate 1M functions and invoke it one from another and get it as well.

Comment: Also you are passing in the return values of functions and not the functions themselves which seems wrong to me since the argument name is `callback`. unless the functions return functions

Comment: @Logan Murphy: it's not. In my comment I was talking about 1M distinct functions, none of which directly or indirectly invokes itself.

Comment: @Logan Murphy - Oh yes they return functions...I think. It is pretty confusing all of this callback, continuation, async, monad stuff I am trying to put it all together right now. Mess land.

Comment: @zerkms although it is possible, very unlikely. do you have an example of which this might occur? just curious, maybe it is common

Comment: @Logan Murphy: I didn't talk about probability of this to happen in real life. My points are: 1. You don't need recursion to get stack overflow. 2. The stack depth here is not equal to 1

Comment: @zerkms can't really say what the depth is without more code

Comment: @Logan Murphy: it's definitely > 1. Every nested callback increments the depth value. Here we see 5 functions, 4 of which have increments. So if passed correctly (as per design idea) - the depth will increase by at least 5 calls (if observed in the most nested callback body)

Comment: @cris if `updateUI` or `updateIndexedDB` or `processResponseInWorker` or `get` don't return a function then i think you might be in some trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` will not call the provided functions unless there is no other code running.

As is demonstrated in [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/e64ZM/1) the timeout, although it is a 0 millisecond delay, will not execute until no other code is being executed. That is the nature of classic javascript (synchronized).

```
console.log(1);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(2);
}, 0);
console.log(3);
for(var i = 4; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Initially lets assume the depth is 0. Let's assume that no functions other than the callbacks and the functions in the original code are called

```
updateUI()
```

Call the function `updateUI` our depth becomes 1. We return a function from this function and our depth becomes 0 again and we have something that essentially looks like this.

```
updateIndexedDB(function(){})
```

So we call `updateIndexedDB` and our depth becomes 1 which calls the provided callback function and our depth becomes 2. The callback returns and depth becomes 1 and `updateIndexedDB` returns a functions so that we have something looks like this.

```
processResponseInWorker(function() {})
```

Similar process occurs until we have this

```
get(hot_uri, function() {})
```

Again the same thing until we have this

```
handleUserInput(function() {})
```

Without using timeout the max depth i observe is 2 but using timeouts on your callbacks (which i don't know if you can do because i don't know if your callbacks give you future callbacks) your max is 1 since the callbacks will individually be executed after all code has been executed (on their own stack).

I feel like you meant to write your code this way

```
handleUserInput(function() {
    get(hot_uri , function() {
        processResponseInWorker(function() {
            updateIndexedDB(function() {
                updateUI();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

which would result in a depth of 6 again unless you use timeouts which would result in a stack size of 1.